# How to wrap TextBlock content in TreeView?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, treeview

I have `TreeView`, which displays some data using data templates. Here's XAML:

```xml
<TreeView Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Railways}" x:Name="tvDatawareObjects"
          ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
    <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
        </Style>
    </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <!-- other templates here... -->
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:ProjectViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Phases}">
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Code}" FontWeight="DemiBold" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Grid.Row="1" />
            </Grid>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>

        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:CollectionViewModel}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding CollectionName}" />
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

Text wrapping for `<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Grid.Row="1" />` doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it. :)

Accordind to the link, provided in the Dan's answer, the reason is lying in the default TreeViewItemTemplate.

Unfortunately, simple binding to `TreeView.ActualWidth` can't help. This is because width of each item is less than `TreeView.ActualWidth` by definition - items are rendered with some horizontal offset, depending on their level.

Hence, to solve the problem, I need to calculate width of item like this:

```
width = actual_width_of_tree_view - relative_horizontal_offset_of_item
```

To be more precise, I need `ScrollViewer.ViewportWidth`, so as TreeViewContent might be scrolled vertically, and visible area of `TreeView` will be less than `TreeView.ActualWidth` in this case.

Here's attached property:

```
    public static Double GetProjectTitleWidth(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (Double)obj.GetValue(ProjectTitleWidthProperty);
    }

    public static void SetProjectTitleWidth(DependencyObject obj, Double value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(ProjectTitleWidthProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ProjectTitleWidthProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "ProjectTitleWidth", 
        typeof(Double), 
        typeof(DatawareSearchView),
        new UIPropertyMetadata(0.0, ProjectTitleWidthChanged));

    private static void ProjectTitleWidthChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var targetElement = d as FrameworkElement;
        if (targetElement != null)
        {
            var bindingExpr = targetElement.GetBindingExpression(ProjectTitleWidthProperty);
            var sourceElement = bindingExpr.DataItem as FrameworkElement;
            if (sourceElement != null)
            {
                // calculating relative offset
                var leftTop = targetElement.TranslatePoint(new Point(0.0, 0.0), sourceElement);

                // trying to find ScrollViewer
                var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(sourceElement, 0);
                if (border != null)
                {
                    var scrollViewer = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(border, 0) as ScrollViewer;
                    if (scrollViewer != null)
                    {
                        // setting width of target element
                        targetElement.Width = scrollViewer.ViewportWidth - leftTop.X;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

...and markup:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Code}" FontWeight="DemiBold" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Title}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" x:Name="tbTitle" Grid.Row="1"
               localviews:DatawareSearchView.ProjectTitleWidth="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
</Grid>
```

Of course, provided solution isn't universal - it assumes, that TreeView has `Border` and `ScrollViewer`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the `TextBlock` isn't wrapping because it doesn't have a defined width. The grid column that the `TextBlock` is in has a * width which will grow as the `TextBlock` grows in width. Try setting a width on the `TextBlock` or the column and see if the change causes the `TextBlock` to wrap.

**Update:**

To be more specific, the problem is that the `TreeViewItem` will size itself to the size of its contents, the `ColumnDefinition` will fill the (infinitely) available space and the `TextBlock`, with no width restriction, will never wrap. [This post](http://leecampbell.blogspot.com/2009/01/horizontal-stretch-on-treeviewitems.html) does a good job of describing how the TreeViewItem behaves. To sum it up: the content area of the `TreeViewItem` is set to 'Auto' so it will grow to fit the contents. To explicitly set the width of the `TreeViewItem` try binding your `ColumnDefinition` width to the `TreeView`'s `ActualWidth`.

XAML:

```
<TreeView Width="100">
    <TreeViewItem>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=TreeView}, Path=ActualWidth}"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition/>
                <RowDefinition/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum" />
            <TextBlock Text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book." 
                       TextWrapping="Wrap" Grid.Row="1"/>
            </Grid>
        </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: I think, you're confusing "*" and "Auto".
"*" means "fill all available space", "Auto" means "get space as much as needed". In my markup sample, "all available space" must be a width of a TreeViewItem, which renders my data item. Width of TVI, by-turn, must be limited by width of TreeView (this is my assumption), but this doesn't take place.

Comment: thanks for the link, it's nice explanation of problem source. About binding to actual width of TreeView - see my answer below.

Answer (score -2):

try this

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Model.Title}" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,
      ElementName=tvDatawareObjects}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="Gray" Grid.Row="1"/>
```

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. Looks like this binding is ignored. Meanwhile, constant width value works properly. :(